# How can I replace the text in cells in a column?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm building a tool to parse/format copy pasted data into a more organized table.

The final table is 4 columns and the 3rd column is email addresses.

I would like to replace (@gmail.com) in the email address column with a value that says "external email address". The size of the table changes when new data in input.

With my limited knowledge I've not been successful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question. Reading [mcve] might help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be nice if You showed what You mean by "A lot of the stuff is already done" and what You've achieved so far but...

You could try using ***InStr()*** like this,

```
Sub ReplaceExternalEmails()

    'ofc sheet's and listObj's indexes or "names" matters and depends on your case, try to figure these out
    Dim someTable As ListObject
    Set someTable = Sheets(1).ListObjects(1)

    'Loop through 3rd column to check for external mails
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In someTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(3).Cells
        If InStr(cel.Value, "@gmail.com") Then
            cel.Value = "external email address"
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```

You could also add

```
cel.ClearFormats
```

inside for loop, or some other formating so it won't stay underlined blue if You care somehow.

Another way to approach this (which is probably faster with larger datasets) is by replacing values, which is equivalent to **CTRL+F / Replace** method like this,

```
Sub ReplaceExternalEmails()

    Dim someTable As ListObject
    Set someTable = Sheets(1).ListObjects(1)

    Dim fnd As Variant: fnd = "*@gmail.com"
    Dim rpl As Variant: rpl = "external email address"

    someTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(3).Replace _
        What:=fnd, Replacement:=rpl

End Sub
```

Comment: The first set of code worked perfectly!! When I said most of the work is done, its mostly just moving columns around and pivoting the data. I hit a brick wall when I got to this part. However, I had to remove the '.DataBodyRange' bit coz VBA didn't like it for some reason. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your welcome :)

(btw. _**DataBodyRange**_ bit refers to the range you wanna work with. So just the body  of _**someTable**_ - excluding headers. If you replaced it with just _**.Range**_ it will consider everything including headers, totals etc.)

Here You can find detailed info.
https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim lastRow as long, ws as Worksheet, i as long

Set ws = ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("YourWorksheetName")

' Suppose your third column is column C
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
' Suppose the first row is the header, column C = 3 in terms of index
For i = 2 To lastRow
    If ws.Cells(i,3).Value Like "*@gmail.com*" Then
         ws.Cells(i,3).Value = "external email address"
    End If
Next i
```